# Authentication token manipulation error when trying to change use password in dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, passwords

I am trying to change a password for a user I am creating during the run of a dockerfile:

```
RUN groupadd --system ${UNAME} --gid ${UID} && \
    useradd --uid ${UID} --system --gid ${UNAME} --home-dir /home/${UNAME} --create-home --comment "Docker image user" ${UNAME} && \
    chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /home/${UNAME} && \
    usermod -aG sudo ${UNAME}

RUN echo '${UNAME}:password' | chpasswd
```

The second `RUN` command fails with

> ````
> Authentication token manipulation error chpasswd: (line 1, user
> ${UNAME}) password not changed ```
> ````

Doing the very same like so, does work:

```
RUN useradd pi && \
    mkdir -p /home/pi && \
    chown pi /home/pi && \
    echo 'pi:password' | chpasswd
```

I don't understand the difference. I just want to give ${UNAME} a constant password `password`.

Comment: You don't normally log into a Docker container in any meaningful way, and this password can be easily retrieved by looking at the `docker history` of the image.  There's no need for a user password and it's almost impossible to set securely.  I'd suggest removing these lines entirely.

Comment: @DavidMaze I do need a password, because I need to log in to the docker using ssh, which requires a password. This is in order to connect directly into the docker from within PyCharm or Clion.

Comment: @Gulzar can you please confirm whether you got any solution for this issue? Because I am also getting the same issue and totally stuck.

Comment: @NewUser see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76939914/913098). Please say if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working for me now:

use a single `RUN` command for less docker images.

```
RUN groupadd --system ${UNAME} --gid ${UID}
RUN useradd --uid ${UID} --system --gid ${UNAME} --home-dir /home/${UNAME} --create-home --comment "Docker image user" ${UNAME}
RUN chown -R ${UNAME}:${UNAME} /home/${UNAME}
RUN usermod -aG sudo ${UNAME}
RUN echo "${UNAME}  ALL=(ALL) ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/permissions
RUN echo ${UNAME}:password | chpasswd
```

Notice the added line `RUN echo "${UNAME}  ALL=(ALL) ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/permissions`

Comment: Nicely done, more precise than my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: @VonC Thanks! How to get notified on new answers for questions I only answered to? How did you know there is a new answer?

Comment: I [followed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403093/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is not because of the actual password used, as noted in [`moby/moby` issue 5704](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5704#issuecomment-1362575038).

> In my case the password was too simple and needed to use a stronger one, using the capital and small letters, digits and symbols. For ex, `P2sswrd!!!`.

And add an `echo "${UNAME}"` to validate `${UNAME}` has the expected value.

Finally, try

```
RUN echo "${UNAME}:password" | chpasswd
        ^^^               ^^^
```

Using `""` will ensure the variable `${UNAME}` is substituted by its value.